# How to manage datasources with netbeans?

Tags: mysql, jsf, netbeans, glassfish, datasource

Hi I would like to point my current datasource to a new server the only change is address because I have exported my current db to my new one. So I just need to change this. I am using netbeans 6.8 with glassfish 3 (JSF 2.0).

Thank you very much
Best Reagrds
Ignacio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the database connections you use in Netbeans**

Tab services, click open item Databases, rightclick your database connection and select properties.  You can change the server address there.

**For database connections that were deployed to Glassfish**

In the Glassfish admin console, go to Resources, JDBC datapools and change the server connection settings to the new remote server.

**For database connection definitions deployed by the project**
In your Enterprise project, select server resources.  The database connection definition should be there.  Edit to reflect the new situation and redeploy your project.

Comment: where should I add the mysql driver inside glassfish? I thing thank is messing up my gf

Comment: The lib directory in the Glassfish installation directory should be fine.

Comment: I'm installing netbeans in the vps and handle it all toghether from there!

Comment: That can help you short term, however I suggest you try to solve this problem nevertheless, it's not very practical to have to develop in the vps.